# Pandas Plot: Plotting the freq each person visits the park each month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe grouped by month. I want to plot a graph with the x-axis showing each person id and the y axis showing the frequency of trips to the park each month. I would like each month to be a different color. The dataframe consist of an index, month, id, and freq column. The frequency is a calculation of how many times a person visited the park per month.

I've come up with the following two graphs, but I'm unable to figure out how to manipulate the graphs to display what I'm looking for exactly.

[Grouped by Month using it has a group key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC9qG.png)
[Grouped by both Month and Camera ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXhU4.png)

I'm looking for a graph that will show a similar output. The dataset contains nearly a thousand people (y-axis), so I'm open to suggestions for a better format.
[Desired Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQFWH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [seaborn.barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

I have created dummy data based on your desired output.

Data Creation Code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'person_id':['1','1','2','2','3','3','4','4','1','3','3','4','4','1'] \
        ,'month':['Jan','March','Feb','June','Jan','July','April','Dec','Dec','Feb','Oct','Oct','Nov','May'] \
        , 'frequency':[1,1,3,23,23,34,23,24,123,34,324,245,123,34]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[Data Looks Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Rju.png)

The Code for resultant output should be

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
sns.barplot(data=df,x='person_id',y='frequency',hue='month')
plt.xlabel("Person ID")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.title("Person ID v/s Frequency")
plt.show()
```

[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gLuT.png)